# YouTube videos won't start playing unless I switch to that window - how to fix

Tags: youtube

When I play a collection of videos in YouTube, such as in a Mix, I often find I have to switch from the application I'm using back to the web browser, and to the browser tab with the YouTube video in order for it to play. This is inconvenient for me, because I often listen to the videos for the audio rather than watch the video component.

Is this something I can configure to fix? If so, how? Or is it deliberate on YouTube's part, to ensure that I'm actually seeing the videos they're streaming?

I'm using Safari 6.1.6, on OS X Lion.